# Run a Macro from Shape or `Button (Form control)` leads to hang the Excel Ribbon, Office 2016 32_Bit

Tags: excel, vba, freeze, ribbon, commandbutton

`This issue can be produced only on Office 2016`.

I have a sheet with name `Test` , then I hide it manually or by this code:

```
Sub Make_Sheet_Hidden()
    Sheets("Test").Visible = xlSheetHidden
End Sub
```

**Problem**: If the below code `Make Visible` assigned to `Shape` or `Button (Form control)`, and run it then used excel Ribbon, like click on `Bottom Border` this leads to hang the Excel Ribbon.
But, strangely If run the below code from **Command Button**( ActiveX Control) or run from code window , then no problem at all.

```
Sub Make_Sheet_Visible()
    Sheets("Test").Visible = xlSheetVisible
    Sheets("Test").Select
End Sub
```

**Note**: This is the link for the Workbook [Link](https://easyupload.io/q5u8dv)
**to produce the issue** , the sheet `Test` **must first be hidden , then click on** `Shape` or `Button 1`

**Kindly** what is the explanation of that issue and How to solve?
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by **and used excel Ribbon**, after (during) running a piece of code from `Shape` or `Button`?

Comment: @FaneDuru ,Clicked any button on Ribbon , like **Bottom Border**

Comment: When to click such a "button on Ribbon"? During the code run? It should take some milliseconds... After unhiding and activating the sheet?

Comment: There must be more code involved; perhaps on a worksheet event like `Worksheet_Change` or something like that?

Comment: Also, If I understand, you're saying the code works OK when executed from an ActiveX button but not a Form command button....   Are you actually using [UserForms](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/userform-object) in your workbook? If not, you shouldn't be using the form controls.

Comment: The code you show us cannot produce such a 'side effect'. Independent of the running way. There are some Ribbon events (written in XML), triggered by Columns/rows/sheets hiding and some others. Did you play with such events? Are there some events (Activate, for instance) in the sheet your code makes it visible?

Comment: @FanuDuru , I checked again , no events at all on sheet `Test` and no code at all on `ThisWorkbook` and no userforms found , I even deleted that sheet and created a new on (in the same workbook) but the problem as it is. There is no modification with XML ribbon.

Comment: @FaneDuru @ashleedawg , This is workbook , sheet `Test` is hidden , I checked this workbook on two different PC with office 2016 , the same issue on both PC. https://easyupload.io/ri2pwz

Comment: I downloaded it and run the Sub pressing all existing controls. It does not freeze anything. What do you mean by "hang the Excel Ribbon"? Can't you change the Tabs, or what? I am using it in Excel 365 64bit. Did **you** create the workbook in discussion, or you have it from somebody else?

Comment: @FaneDuru It the same workbook with my issue (I just deleted extra sheet ) , to produce the issue , the sheet `Test` must be **hidden** first , then click on `Shape` or `Button 1`.

Comment: This aspect was cristal clear. Of course, I did it in this way...  Did you also try the workbook you sent to me? It maybe have a problem in the deleted sheet. If still problematic, try repairing the Office installation.

Comment: @FaneDuru surely I tried this workbook before sent , and it is not normal that all PC on my office need repair.
kindly ,If you have any PC with office 2016 32Bit, could you try.
It is the `second time` that there are codes work perfectly on** your office 365** and **not work on office 2016 32Bit**

Comment: I am afraid I cannot find such an installation. Everybody I know uses 64bit installations...

Comment: @FaneDuru I just tried on my own laptop (Office 2016 32Bit) unfortunately The same issue Freezing. and tried remotely  (Using Team-viewer) on my home PC (Office 2021 32Bit) and the workbook working with no freeze and fine.So, this problem is related to office 2016, Please How can I debug this issue?

Comment: I did not face such a situation until now, but if you are available I can try connecting to your computer using AnyDesk if you send me your installation ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note 1:**  the above issue happens even there is only one workbook opened in Excel.
**Note 2:**  this issue is not specific with my workbook ,I created new one from scratch and the same issue exists.
**Note 3:**  that issue is specific with office 2016. 
 **Answer:** 
I replaced **Select** in the below line with **Activate**
`Sheets("Test").Select`
So , the good working macro is

```
Sub Make_Sheet_Visible()
    Sheets("Test").Visible = xlSheetVisible
    Sheets("Test"). Activate
    End Sub
```

**Actually: I do not know the technical explanation of why using (Activate) instead of (Select) fixed that issue.**

Comment: @FaneDuru many thanks for your efforts and trying to fix that issue.

Comment: @ashleedawg the above answer just FYI

Comment: @FaneDure I found the answer for the above issue as you can see on the answer , kindly could you help with that additional issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70798498/truncated-words-in-text-box-how-to-fix-see-attached-picture